# Getting the latest message between 2 people in a conversation Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find a solution wherein I can return a list of the latest chats between 2 users with their last message in it. I have gone across multiple articles and have seen that with the help of aggregate I will be able to achieve this. However, upon trying the code below I still get an extra/duplicate document. Is there anyway I can filter this even more to make sure that there is ONLY 1 document per person (to or fro)

```
Chat.aggregate(
  [{ $match: { $or: [{ "sender._id": senderId }, { "reciever._id": senderId }] } },
  { $sort: { time: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "last_message_between": {
          $cond: [
            {
              $gt: [
                { $substr: ["$reciever._id", 0, 1] },
                { $substr: ["$sender._id", 0, 1] }]
            },
            { $concat: ["$sender._id", " and ", "$reciever._id"] },
            { $concat: ["$reciever._id", " and ", "$sender._id"] }
          ]
        }
      },
      "message": { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  }], function (err, data) {
    if (err || !data) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: err,
      });
    }
    res.json(data);
  })
```

[image: Mongo Output]

Comment: You are misspelling 'receiver'. I am confused how many documents you are trying to return, 1 or more than 1?

Comment: Also the only two relevant tags to this question are mongodb and mongodb-query.

Comment: I am trying to return only 1 document (latest one) doesn't matter who's sending the message, the model needs to send back only one latest document.

in this instance - the model should only send the first element, wherein it sends 2. One where the receiver has sent a message and another vice versa.

Apologies for the grammatical error will correct the backend :)

Comment: Why does $limit 1 after sorting not work?

Comment: Doesn't . For example say there are 3 chats
1- A -> B
2. A -> C
3. B -> A
With limit 1 I only get one chat (A -> B).

Comment: You said you wanted one result, so what is the problem there?

Comment: With the given example I would expect the model to return 2 chats
1- A-> B (or B-> A  depending how one which ones the latest) 2. A-> C. Notice that only one item is picked up between those 2 chats (the latest one). My code does that but the only con is that it's bindirevtional it returns both (latest chat between B-> A and A-> B) hope that helps :) again, thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It doesn't, I cannot follow what it is that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of compraing the two ids with `$cond` was good.

But to make it work in every cases, you just have to compare the whole string instead of just the first characters.

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZjiT1HbU3qt)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "sender._id": "user_1@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "receiver._id": "user_1@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      time: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "last_message_between": {
          $cond: [
            {
              $gt: [
                "$receiver._id",
                "$sender._id"
              ]
            },
            {
              $concat: [
                "$sender._id",
                " and ",
                "$receiver._id"
              ]
            },
            {
              $concat: [
                "$receiver._id",
                " and ",
                "$sender._id"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "message": {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: You sir are an absolute legend. Worked like a charm. If there's anyway I could buy you a coffee please let me know :)

Comment: Ahah thanks a lot, but it was no big deal. Have a nice day :)